# Can quicksilver sash remove Airborne?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is this item able to remove airborne? To be more specific, during Yasuo's ult, can this item or Mercurial Scimitar dismiss the effect of Yasuo's ult?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [League of legends: What is the difference between knock-up and suppression effect?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57974/league-of-legends-what-is-the-difference-between-knock-up-and-suppression-effec)

Comment: @mbomb007 That is not a duplicate of this question. It just so happens that the answer to that question also answers this one, but that does not mean the question itself is a duplicate.

Comment: @MageXy The rule of thumb according to the meta is "If you ask a question similar to another question and it is likely to get the exact same answer, you have yourself a duplicate question." In this case, the answer *already* exists, so the likelihood is no longer in question. This question could be closed as a dup, which will then *point* at what it's a duplicate of, showing any lookers to the question with the info they seek.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Quicksilver_Sash)-

> The active does not cancel or remove Airborne directly, but allows wielders to use mobility spells and  Flash to overrule the effect.

So, used in conjunction with Flash, or a similar spell, you can remove the effects of airborne. This works not only with yasuo's knock up, but also with malphite and others who also have knock up abilities.

From what I understand about how knock ups work (from listening to casters of professional games) there are two parts to a knock up; the initial knock up which works similar to a knock back, and a secondary stun that immediately follows and lasts until the animation of your character falling to the ground completes. The qss will remove this secondary stun allowing you to issue movement commands again, but only movement spells like dashes or blinks break the falling animation and allow you to move again.

Comment: Verified. Used with flash, qss can get you out of yasuo's ult.

Comment: Speaking of Yasuo's Ult, is the applied damage effected by this if yes how?

Comment: @empiric can get you out of the CC, but not the damage.